# Change background opacity of a less variable

Tags: css, less

I have the following [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) variable: `@yellow:#fbba00;`

I want to apply this color to the background of a `tr` with `opacity: 0.2` .

I tried the following, but the problem is that the opacity is applied to **the whole tr**, and not **only to the background**.

I saw several topics dealing with background opacities ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-color-but-not-the-text), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)), but they always use `rgba()` to set the color. It does not match what I am looking for (LESS variable).

---

**In LESS/CSS file:**

```
@yellow: #fbba00;

.bg-light-yellow {
    background-color: @yellow;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

**In HTML page:**

```
<tr class="bg-light-yellow">
    ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

Per [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860874/how-to-convert-hex-color-to-rgba-with-less-compiler), LESS has an embedded function for this called `fade`.

```
fade(@color, 50%);   // return @color with 50% transparency in rgba
```

So this

```
@yellow: #fbba00;

.bg-light-yellow {
    background-color: fade(@yellow, 20%);
}
```

complies to this

```
.bg-light-yellow {
  background-color: rgba(251, 186, 0, 0.2);
}
```

[**LESS Reference**](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade)