# How to convert hex color to rgba in Emotion

Tags: css, reactjs, less, emotion

I am converting styles of my app from Less to [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction)

in Less I have styles as follows:

```
@blue: #476882;
background: rgba(red(@blue), green(@blue), blue(@blue), 0.5);
```

while converting to Emotion I am doing this:

```
export const BLUE = '#476882'
background: rgba(red(${BLUE}), green(${BLUE}), blue(${BLUE}), 0.5);
```

however it is not working.

[image]

any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: All IDEs has this as default, or as a plugin. Try that, good luck (Color Picker)

Comment: Instead of this:
background: rgba(red(${BLUE}), green(${BLUE}), blue(${BLUE}), 0.5);
Try:
background: rgba(${RED},${GREEN},${BLUE}, 0.5);

Comment: I have the hex color `BLUE`and I dont want to create 3 variables `RED, GREEN and BLUE`

Comment: Will `background-color:${BLUE}; opacity:0.5` work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert HEX color to rgba with Less compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860874/how-to-convert-hex-color-to-rgba-with-less-compiler)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any method within emotion, but I personally solved it with an utility function that uses the [hex-rgb](https://github.com/sindresorhus/hex-rgb) package:

```
import hexRgb from 'hex-rgb';

export const rgba = (hex, alpha) => {
  const rgb = hexRgb(hex, { format: 'array' })
    .slice(0, -1)
    .join(',');
  return `${rgb},${alpha}`;
};
```

and then just use it like so: `rgba(${rgba('#000', 0.15)})`

Answer (score 0):

The simple converter, without any dependencies.

```js
export const hexToRgba = (hex: string, alpha: string | number): string => {
  const result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);

  return result
    ? `rgba(${parseInt(result[1], 16)}, ${parseInt(result[2], 16)}, ${parseInt(
        result[3],
        16,
      )}, ${alpha})`
    : hex;
};
```