# transparency for table cell div

Tags: css, internet-explorer

My markup is below. The `background` property of the `#template` element is set to `rgba`, with some transparency. In IE9 the transparency does not seem to work. If I remove the `display: table-cell` from `#template` style then transparency works but the cell is not 100% high anymore. This is only in IE. It works in Chrome. Did not try with FF.

I am looking for help figuring out why this is happening and how to fix it.

I know that if I remove the `display: table-...` styles, it works, but I need these styles for my layout. Except for the `display: table-cell` for `#template`, which I did not have originally, but discovered that without it, IE9 does not make it 100% high. I need it to be 100% high.

http://jsfiddle.net/d6nUN/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #container {
        display: table;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #container #content {
        background-color: #ff6622;
        display: table-row;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #template {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        display: table-cell;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content">
        <div id="template">text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to stretch `#template` this way:

```
#template {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pfUe7/2/

Comment: yes, it works thank you. I cannot use absolute positioning, these elements are a part of a bigger layout, the sample that I have posted is contrived. `#template` needs to be positioned inside a table row.

Comment: So what is the problem? you just set `position: relative` for the parent container.

Comment: here is the live page that I am trying to fix: http://kamyanov-art.com/#/contact In Chrome, the background picture is covered with white tint, in IE9 only the part of it is covered. This happens because `#template` does not have `table-cell` property, but if I add it, the alpha disappears.

Comment: Works fine for me in IE9. `#template {position: absolute; top: 148px; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;}` (+ remove `height: 100%`). `#content {position: relative}`. 148px is the height of the header.

Comment: the live site also has a footer which must be at the bottom of the contents, or at the bottom of the window, whatever is bigger. absolute positioning breaks that at least. looks like i will need to have conditional CSS for IE specifically...

Comment: Conditional CSS for IE is okay if that is what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and saw the following:

[rgba background with IE filter alternative: IE9 renders both!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506085/rgba-background-with-ie-filter-alternative-ie9-renders-both)

Try the following declaration in your `#template` rule set:

```
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(30);
```

You may have to make this CSS rule specific to IE9 but at least you can use `table-cell`.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx